Issues with :has and a grid modification in one code but same code works on an other page
I've tried multiple modifications and still can't find my issue with a part of my code which is working as expected in an other sheet.
When I go hover my #div3, nothing change expect the fact that my text from #div1 disapear, when I :hover the #div1, no problem. I tried to remove my grid-column and grid row from #div3 and it just create new rows and columns in my grid.
Here is the code :


.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 39vw);
    grid-template-rows: 10vh 10vh 40vh;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    column-gap: 1%;
    grid-template-areas:
    " e e "
    " a b "
    " c d " ;
}
#h3 {
    grid-area: e;
    grid-column: 1/3;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    background-color: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#h3 p {
    background-color: inherit;
    font-size: 4vb;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
#div1 {
    grid-area: a ;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #272727;
}
#div2 {
    grid-area: b ;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #272727;
}
#div3 {
    grid-area: c;
    grid-row: 3/4;
    grid-column: 1/2;
}
#div4 {
    grid-area: d;
    grid-row: 3/4;
    grid-column: 2/3;
}
#div4 img, #div3 img{
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#div1:hover, #div2:hover{
   z-index: 2;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 80%;
    color: black;
}
#div1 p, #div2 p{
    align-self: center;
    background-color: inherit;
}
.container:has(#div1:hover){
    grid-template-areas: 
    "e e"
    "a b"
    "a d";
    z-index: 2;
}
.container:has(#div3:hover){
    grid-template-areas: 
    "e e"
    "a b"
    "a d";
    z-index: 2;
}
.container:has(#div4:hover, #div2:hover){
    grid-template-areas: 
    "e e"
    "a b"
    "c b";  
    z-index: 2;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Illustrator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/illu.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nom">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Mon Travail</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:cool.email@gmail.com">Me Contacter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        <div id="header"><header><H3>Mes travaux Illustrator</H3></header></div>
    </div>
   
</body>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="h3"><p>Vous voudriez peut être jeter un oeil à ...</p></div>
        <div id="div1"><p>Mes travaux InDesign</p></div>
        <div id="div2"><p>Mes travaux Acrobat</p></div>
        <div id="div3"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMuj6_VR3oP0fa_jDFqoy3Hjy3xq0SlQjRLRnoAteoGQ&s" alt="InDesign"></div>
        <div id="div4"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Adobe_Acrobat_Reader_icon_%282020%29.svg/2101px-Adobe_Acrobat_Reader_icon_%282020%29.svg.png" alt="Acrobat"></div>
    </div>
</footer>
</html>




I have converted your code into a snippet. It would help if you can edit it and add relevant html.

From what i see on the snippet you have the correct behavior on both div1 and div3 :o what is the problem ? (edit: ok I think I understand what you want > the image header to disappear completly hen hovering the image ?)
